# Is it possible to wait for user action before further execution of jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to create .ipynb notebook which will ask user for some inputs passed via `ipywidget` widgets. I don't want the user to be forced to scroll through the whole notebook and run cells manually after inserting inputs - instead they should click `Run all` button and then be guided through the whole process. Simple example:

1. User clicks `Run all` and kernel starts. First 10 cells (containing import statements and other fixed code) executes.
2. Cell nr 11 is supposed to ask the user for input - it contains `DatePicker` widget and the user is asked to select the date for which they want to find records from database to be displayed later. **User should be  automatically taken to this cell, without scrolling**.
3. User clicks the date and sees confirm button (another widget, a button with text "Selected date: ... Click here to continue") - Notebook won't continue until user clicks this button.
4. User click the button and notebook execution continues. The rest 30 cells in notebook execute without user actions.
5. Last cell in the notebook displays some data. Again, user is automatically taken to this cell without scrolling.

Comment: A better approach would be a Voila dashboard that you build using the notebook itself & the widgets. I have an example where you pick what data to plot; it isn't working right now because mybinder has an issue launching for now. (The static version isn't convincing but is at https://nbviewer.org/github/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder/blob/master/3D_scatter_Voila_matplotlibSTREAMLINED.ipynb) .... And Voici, the JupyterLite version of Voici, is still challenging. ... That 'Run All' paradigm you describe doesn't really exist but you could maybe put in a simple `input()` step to hang things up.

Comment: @Wayne thanks, I've already started reading about voila and tried to run my notebook with it - one thing I still don't get how to halt execution and wait for user action - I tried adding `input()` cell but then: `StdinNotImplementedError: raw_input was called, but this frontend does not support input requests`. I'll keep reading more and try to figure it out but if you already know what to do about it let me know :)

Comment: The `input()` suggestion was if you wanted to keep your post idea of using an actual notebook to run things. Only Jupyter widgets, and compatible widgets, work with Voila. ..... I cannot tell what frontend you are using. `input()` alone in a cell works in a standard Jupyter. I thought `raw_input()` was from Python 2.